# Getting NSData from UIImage object that contains CGImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, nsdata, cgimage

In order to upload an image file to my server, I need to get it's NSData. I am having trouble doing this right now, because my UIImage contains a CGImage.

Let me show you how I am doing things. When a user takes a photo, this is what I do with the captured photo:

```
NSData *imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageDataSampleBuffer];


UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc]initWithData:imageData];


   _subLayer = [CALayer layer];


      image = [self selfieCorrection:image];


      image = [self rotate:image andOrientation:image.imageOrientation];


          CGRect cropRectFinal = CGRectMake(cropRect.origin.x, 140, cropRect.size.width, cropRect.size.height);

          CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([image CGImage], cropRectFinal);


_subLayer.contents = (id)[UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef].CGImage;
```

In the above code, I create a UIImage, and initialize it with the `imageData` object. I also create a layer object called `_subLayer` that will display the final image on the screen. The image's orientation is then rotated and corrected, and then I setup a CGRect to crop the part of the image I want to keep.

The most important part are the last 2 statements. I create a CGImageRef called `imageRef` using the original UIImage. Then, in the last statement, I set the contents property of `_subLayer` to equal my final image.

A little further down in this same view controller, inside of an IBAction I have the following statement which helps me pass the image to my next view controller:         `sendFriendsVC.finalPhotoToSend = _subLayer.contents;`

`finalPhotoToSend` is a property that I have setup in the header file of my next view controller like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage *finalPhotoToSend;
```

The data is successfully passed when I segue to the next view controller, but when I NSLog `finalPhotoToSend`, even though it is a UIImage, it prints as this to the console:

```
<CGImage 0x1563dac0>
```

In order to upload photos to my backend server service, it requires me to create an object using NSData. I have tried using these 2 methods to get the NSData out of the `finalPhotoToSend` object:

```
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(finalPhotoToSend, 0.7);
```

and

```
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(finalPhotoToSend);
```

But those always give me the following error in xcode:

```
NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFType CGImage]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

I am not sure what to do. Is there a different method I should be using to get NSData out of my UIImage since it is technically holding a CGImage? Should I be doing something differently before I even pass the data to my next view controller?

Edit for Michael:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:self {


    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"mediaCaptureToSendToFriendsSegue"]) {


    SendToFriendsViewController *sendFriendsVC = segue.destinationViewController;


        sendFriendsVC.finalPhotoToSend = _subLayer.contents;


    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Better answer:***

You need to truly set a UIImage object (and not a CGImage pointer) to a property that you've declared to be a UIImage object.

***Original:***

if "`finalPhotoToSend`" is a property, you should be doing:

```
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.finalPhotoToSend, 0.7);
```

and not:

```
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(finalPhotoToSend, 0.7);
```

Comment: that was a typo. I am using it as a global variable: _finalPhotoTosend. Either way, that's not the problem. I need to figure out a solution in regards to getting the NSData from the object.

Comment: can you edit your question to show you how set the "`finalPhotoToSend`" property?

Comment: just to be sure, I did include the statement: sendFriendsVC.finalPhotoToSend = _subLayer.contents;    But I will edit the question and add the full IBAction that contains this statement.

Comment: Oh yeah, there I see it.  So when you do "`_subLayer.contents = (id)[UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef].CGImage`", you're setting "`.contents`" to a CGImage and not a UIImage.  And you can't do "`UIImageJPEGRepresentation`" off a CGImage.  No wonder you're getting that exception.

Comment: I understand, but then why am I able to store this CGImage in the UIImage object finalPhotoToSend? Even though I'm storing it in a UIImage, is it technically still a CGImage?

Comment: Because you're just setting an address of an object and not yet calling a method on that object. You attempt to do something with that object when you call "`UIImageJPEGRepresentation`", which is why it's bombing out with an exception.  Why not set that property to a true UIImage object and not a CGImage (which is a CFType and not even an Objective-C object)?  Then your problem should magically disappear.

Comment: Yep exactly. I still have a lot of learning to do with objective-c, but appreciate your patience and help Michael. Thanks again.

Comment: I am really glad you got it solved (and summarized it nicely in your own follow-up answer).

Answer (score 3):

I just figured it out. Here's what I ended up using for the IBAction method implementation:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:self {


    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"mediaCaptureToSendToFriendsSegue"]) {


        SendToFriendsViewController *sendFriendsVC = segue.destinationViewController;


        UIImage* image2 = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:(__bridge CGImageRef)(_subLayer.contents)];

        sendFriendsVC.finalPhotoToSend = image2;


    }
}
```

I'm new to objective-c and not really entirely sure what the following statement is even doing:

```
UIImage* image2 = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:(__bridge CGImageRef)(_subLayer.contents)];
```

But xcode suggested it and it works. Now on the next view controller, the `finalPhotoToSend` object NSLogs as a UIImage instead of a CGImage.